# How to correctly load razor views via RazorLight - first request is pretty long

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razorlight

I have created following simple Razor View:

**EmailTemplates/Reset.cshtml:**

```
@model ResetTemplateDto
Rest email @Model.Title
```

I have called this razor view something like this (via [RazorLight](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight)):

I am loading Razor Views like `EmbeddedResources`:

```
var engine = new RazorLightEngineBuilder()
                .UseEmbeddedResourcesProject(typeof(Program))
                .UseMemoryCachingProvider()
                .Build();

            string result = await _razorLightEngine.CompileRenderAsync("EmailTemplates.Reset", new ResetTemplateDto
            {
                Title = "Test"
            });
```

If I call this request for the first time this action takes perhaps 4-5s, another calls take 100ms.

Is there any solution how to load razor views without this first long request?

Comment: On the first call the template is being rendered while any subsequent call can reuse the already rendered template.

Comment: I have tried render after this first request absolutely different template and another call was really quick. So I do not know where is the issue - it is first call of this library - not first loading specific template. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, i'm having a similar problem. Did you found the solution?

Comment: Yes, I loaded all templates into memory in the Program.cs. Then you can load templates from the memory, not every single request load the whole razor view.